# Установка значений Spacing и Margins по умолчанию для QBoxLayot в PyQt6

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, pyqt6

Как установить значения по умолчанию `Spacing` и `Margins` для всех контейнеров приложения?

В данный момент создание `layouts` выглядит примерно так:

```
layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
....
layout15 = QHBoxLayout()
```

и каждому из них приходится устанавливать `Spacing` и `Margins`

```
layout1.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
layout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
....
layout15.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

layout1.setSpacing(0)
layout2.setSpacing(0)
....
layout15.setSpacing(0)
```

чувствую есть возможность не писать лишних 30 строк кода, но найти ее самостоятельно не могу.

В документации Qt есть сведение о том что стандартный размер отступов зависит от системы (и составляет для большинства систем 11рх), но не указанно как игнорировать это значение.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс [**QBoxLayout**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html) выстраивает дочерние виджеты горизонтально или вертикально.

И выглядит это так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 


class BoxLayout(QBoxLayout):                                              # !!! 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)                               # !!!
        self.setSpacing(0)                                                # !!!
        

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        layout = BoxLayout(QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)                        # QHBoxLayout
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        label = QLabel("Label 1")
        label.setStyleSheet('background-color: #B52B65;')
        layout.addWidget(label, 0)
        
        label1 = QLabel("Label 2")
        label1.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ED6663;')
        layout.addWidget(label1, 0 )
        
        layout2 = BoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)                        # QVBoxLayout
        layout.addLayout(layout2)
        
        labe3 = QLabel("Label 3")
        labe3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #4E9F3D;')
        layout2.addWidget(labe3, 0)
        labe4 = QLabel("Label 4")
        labe4.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D8E9A8;')
        layout2.addWidget(labe4, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за решение, познавательно и довольно элегантно. А нет ли случайно в вашем багаже знаний решения через использования os.environ. Например проблему масштабирования в Windows я подглядел можно решать так:  os.environ["QT_FONT_DPI"] = "96" Может есть похожее отключение навязываемых 11рх от системы?

Comment: @inesta пожалуйста. Я не думаю что вам надо что-то искать, чтобы что-то отключить. Нормальная практика когда вы создаете подкласс , наследуясь от нужного вам класса и в нем переопределяете все что вам надо.

Comment: @inesta если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.